# Where does the 'self' come from? Putting a member function as target for threading.Thread

Tags: python, multithreading

in the following code

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    def do(self):
        print(self.x)

foo1 = foo(1)
foo2 = foo(2)
t1=threading.Thread(target=foo1.do)
t2=threading.Thread(target=foo2.do)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

I am using the member function of an instantiated object as target for the thread. I was wondering why it works, i.e. does the threading module do something special to detect if there is a **member** function (as opposed to a "normal" function w/o object context) at the other end of the callable-Reference? I think the usual callback mechanism like in ftplib.retrlines() et al will only accept plain global functions. Is it better to stay away from this alltogether?

slarti

PS: coming from C/C++ the exposed behaviour is new to me (although welcome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo1.do` and `foo2.do` are bound methods.

I suggest you look at the following documentation links:

- http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#methods (introduction)
- http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html (in depth)

Excerpt from the second link:

> When a bound user-defined method object is called, the underlying
>   function (im_func) is called, inserting the class instance (im_self)
>   in front of the argument list. For instance, when C is a class which
>   contains a definition for a function f(), and x is an instance of C,
>   calling x.f(1) is equivalent to calling C.f(x, 1).

Answer (score 4):

You might want to read about Python's [method objects](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects).

Python's `self` is sort of like C++'s `this`, except you have to put it in the method declaration.

What happens that when you declare a function inside a class, it “becomes” a *method*. When you get a method of an object, it becomes a *bound method*, which has the first argument (`self`) fixed to the object you got it from.

Try:

```
class Foo(object):
    def do(self):
        print x

instance = Foo()
print Foo.do  # prints <unbound method Foo.do>
print instance.do  # prints <bound method Foo.do of <...>>

# These are equivalent:
Foo.do(instance)
instance.do()
```

No extra magic is happening in your Threading case, it's just regular Python.

Comment: The function only gets bound as a method when you reference it: `foo = Foo(); (foo.do is foo.do) == False`. Each reference is a different method (but the same instance and function object).

Comment: Yes. By the *get* in *When you get a method of an object, it becomes a bound method*, I meant attribute access. It's kind of hard to say this succinctly; the tutorial I linked to has the details but it's a bit hard to digest.

Comment: I was clarifying the following: "when you declare a function inside a class, it becomes a method". I just wanted to highlight that it only becomes a bound/unbound method when it's accessed with the descriptor protocol. Otherwise someone might expect separately created references to the 'same' method to actually be the same object.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's why if you put a function into a class after the class is created, it'll behave normally (“become” a method). But it's too much of a detail IMO, and would make the answer less clear, so I'll leave it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you wrote the same class in C++:

```
class foo {
    int x;
  public:
    foo(int x_) { x = x_; }
    void do() { std::cout << x; }
}

foo f = foo(42);
```

Here `&foo::do` would be a pointer to member function and you would need a `foo` instance to be able to call it. Suppose you could pass around `f.do`: then you wouldn't need anything else to call `do()` on `f`. This is exactly what a bound member is in Python and by passing `foo1.do` you are passing both the method to call and the instance onm which to call it.

This same problem has been addressed in C++ either with proprietary extensions, such as Borland's closures, or with libraries, such as [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html).

Comment: The question then remains what global functions are bound against? The mechanism in Python works seamlessly across global and member functions.

Comment: They don't need to be bound against anything, just like C/C++ function pointers. Uniformity is a boon of dynamic typing.

Answer (score 0):

In any instance (non-static) method in a class, the method should be using some variables in the instance of the class thats its running in right? So, every instance method needs a copy the object thats running it to access these variables. That is what `self` is, a copy of the object thats running the method.

In most languages, its implicitly a parameter in instance methods (so you don't really need to write out `self` in the method, but its there`, but in python its explicitly shown, so you have a parameter called`self` in every instance method. It does not change anything, it's just a sort of more obvious way of showing whats happening.

Comment: I think I didn't make myself clear enough. I roughly know the Python way of object orientation, but how and why does the "function pointer" (sorry for the C-ish terminology) of the threading object decide if it needs a "self" reference riding on its back when calling the thread code.

Comment: Sorry, I was way off target in my answer.